# Can't debug with micro cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a application deployed to a Micro Cloud Foundry instance on my local machine. I can start, stop and update the application from within STS. For some reason, the debug options are disabled when I right click on the application or the server from within STS. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug feature is introduced in MCF 1.2.0. Make sure you have the correct version of MCF.
When you add your MCF as a server, you can double click on it and have it open on the window as a tab. You then need to click on the Applications tab (which is on the lower left bottom of your MCF window). You should see a list of your pushed apps. Click on any and you should see the Debug button next to the Start button appear.

There isn't any flags to be set in order for debug to appear or not. It is there in MCF 1.2.0

Comment: Thanks @Ali. I think for most people, this would be the correct answer so I'll accept it. I'm running MCF 1.2.0 but it's still not working for me. I'll post additional data when I figure out what's going on.